# Bigcommerce Pagination Not Working

Tags: bigcommerce

I am currently working with Bigcommerce's Built-in Blog. Everything is working fine now except the pagination. I tried to remove and bring it back and I even tried to place it on the bottom of the page. But still not working. I am not good with jQuery nor JavaScript, so please bear with me. Here's the existing code that I am currently working on:

the website's link is here: 
http://abulafia4.mybigcommerce.com/blog/

```
<body class="blog" id="blog-main">
    <!-- Facebok Plugin -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- added this for the custom css of the blog page -->
    <link href="%%Asset_Styles/custom-blog.css%%" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="%%Asset_Styles/bootstrap.min.css%%" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



    <div class="page-wrap">
        %%Panel.Header%%

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                %%Panel.WrapperBanner%%
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                    <h1 class="TitleHeading">%%GLOBAL_BlogName%%</h1><!-- built in blog codes started here -->
                        <div class="PageContent">
                            %%SNIPPET_RecentPostsContent%%
                            <div class="product-nav btm">
                                <div class="Moveable Panel PagingBottom" id="CategoryPagingBottom">
                                    <div class="CategoryPagination BloggingPagination" >
                                        <ul class="pagination">
                                            <li>Pages</li>
                                            AAAAAAAA
                                            <!-- %%GLOBAL_SectionPaging%%
                                            %%GLOBAL_SectionPagingPrevious%%
                                            %%GLOBAL_SectionPagingNext%% -->
                                        </ul>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br class="Clear">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- built in blog codes ends here -->
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 sidebar-border">
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- SEARCH BAR FOR BLOG ARTICLE -->
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 sidebar-widget">
                                %%Panel.BlogRecentPosts%%
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 sidebar-widget">
                                %%Panel.FacebookPlugin%%
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 sidebar-widget">
                                %%Panel.FollowUs%%
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Sidebar -->
        %%Panel.Footer%%
    </div>

    <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools --> <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-59ccab5868d78bdc"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: hey, whey you commenting this code <!-- %%GLOBAL_SectionPaging%%
                                            %%GLOBAL_SectionPagingPrevious%%
                                            %%GLOBAL_SectionPagingNext%% --> remove comment

Comment: hello @RajKumarBhardwaj, I tried removing the comment. But the code still didn't work.